# How to pass a Go function as an argument to a C function?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I'm trying to pass a Go function to a C function.

Something like:

```golang
stm := C.struct_tray_menu{
    ....
    fn: // definition of method
    ....
}
C.menu_cb(stm);
```

and pass that into a C function:

```c
static void menu_cb(struct tray_menu *item) {
  (void)item;
  printf("menu: clicked on %s\n", item->text);
}
```

I'd just like to know how to define something like C.function.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on callbacks? https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#function-pointer-callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem is misunderstanding of definition of go in c. 
so final code is look like

```golang
//export callOnMeGo
func callOnMeGo(in int) int {
    fmt.Printf("Go.callOnMeGo(): called with arg = %d\n", in)
    return  in+ 1
}

func main() {

    C.some_c_func((C.callback_fcn)(unsafe.Pointer(C.callOnMeGo_cgo)))
    //dont forget to use (funcDefinedInGO_cgo) for with postfix _cgo

...
```